# YubiHSM2: Working command sequence in yubihsm-shell won't work non-interactively on command line

Tags: yubico, yubihsm

I got a working sequence of commands within yubihsm-shell, but cannot get the same result when calling the shell non-interactively from the command line.

In the shell I got:

```
yubihsm> connect
yubihsm> session open 2 MyPassword
yubihsm> set informat base64
yubihsm> set outformat hex
yubihsm> decrypt oaep 0 0x1ddd rsa-oaep-sha1 wrapped_ephemeral.txt
```

On the command line I have currently this (I unfortunately need to be on Windows for that, so this cmd syntax)

```
set YUBISHELL="c:\Program Files\Yubico\YubiHSM Shell\bin\yubihsm-shell.exe"

type wrapped_ephemeral.txt | %YUBISHELL%                                     ^
                               --authkey=2                                   ^
                               --password=MyPassword                         ^
                               --algorithm=rsa-oaep-sha1                     ^
                               --informat=base64                             ^
                               --outformat=hex                               ^
                               --object-id=7645                              ^
                               --action=decrypt-oaep
```

All I'll get is

```
Session keepalive set up to run every 15 seconds
Created session 0
Command not implemented: Generic error
```

However, connecting and authenticating works ...

```
%YUBISHELL%                  ^
  --authkey=2                ^
  --password=MyPassword      ^
  --action=get-device-info
```

... as I get this

```
Using default connector URL: http://127.0.0.1:12345
Session keepalive set up to run every 15 seconds
Version number:         2.2.0
Serial number:          ........
Log used:               62/62
Supported algorithms:   rsa-pkcs1-sha1, rsa-pkcs1-sha256, rsa-pkcs1-sha384,
                        rsa-pkcs1-sha512, rsa-pss-sha1, rsa-pss-sha256,
                        rsa-pss-sha384, rsa-pss-sha512, rsa2048,
                        rsa3072, rsa4096, ecp256,
                        ecp384, ecp521, eck256,
                        ecbp256, ecbp384, ecbp512,
                        hmac-sha1, hmac-sha256, hmac-sha384,
                        hmac-sha512, ecdsa-sha1, ecdh,
                        rsa-oaep-sha1, rsa-oaep-sha256, rsa-oaep-sha384,
                        rsa-oaep-sha512, aes128-ccm-wrap, opaque-data,
                        opaque-x509-certificate, mgf1-sha1, mgf1-sha256,
                        mgf1-sha384, mgf1-sha512, template-ssh,
                        aes128-yubico-otp, aes128-yubico-authentication, aes192-yubico-otp,
                        aes256-yubico-otp, aes192-ccm-wrap, aes256-ccm-wrap,
                        ecdsa-sha256, ecdsa-sha384, ecdsa-sha512,
                        ed25519, ecp224, rsa-pkcs1-decrypt,
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Command not implemented: Generic error" is meant seriously and is not due an mistake by me.

Incomprehensibly, some commands are only available in the interactive mode of the shell.

> Known Issues and Limitations
>
> Unimplemented Commands When Invoked in Command-Line Mode
> ...
>
> - decrypt-oaep
>   ...

(https://developers.yubico.com/YubiHSM2/Releases/Known_issues.html)